# SQL Server - running daily jobs with r scipts

Tags: r, sql-server, jobs

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas on how to set up a SQL Server Job to run r scripts? Here is what I have so far in terms of the SQL code: I have to extract data out of a database (ETL) and want that data to be aggregated/analyzed by R by a specified date. After that, the database would run automatically. Does anybody have any ideas where the SQL ETL Code (from the database) will go and where the R script procedure would go that would eventually run automatically? Thanks!

DATABASE -> ETL Code from database (generating own dataset) -> Using ONLY that dataset where an R script can then manipulate/transform it.

DECLARE @job_name NVARCHAR(128), 
            @description NVARCHAR(512), 
            @owner_login_name NVARCHAR(128), 
            @database_name NVARCHAR(128);

```
SET @job_name = N'Some Title';
SET @description = N'Periodically do something';
SET @owner_login_name = N'login';
SET @database_name = N'DATABASE';

-- Delete job if it already exists:
IF EXISTS(SELECT job_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE (name = @job_name))
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job
        @job_name = @job_name;
END

EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job
    @job_name=@job_name, 
    @enabled=1, 
    @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
    @notify_level_email=2, 
    @notify_level_netsend=2, 
    @notify_level_page=2, 
    @delete_level=0, 
    @description=@description, 
    @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
    @owner_login_name=@owner_login_name;

 -- Add server:
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=@job_name;

 -- Add step to execute SQL:
 EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
     @job_name=@job_name,
     @step_name=N'Execute SQL', 
     @step_id=1, 
     @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
     @on_success_action=1, 
     @on_fail_action=2, 
     @retry_attempts=0, 
     @retry_interval=0, 
     @os_run_priority=0, 
     @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
     @command=N'EXEC my_stored_procedure; -- OR ANY SQL STATEMENT', 
     @database_name=@database_name, 
     @flags=0;

-- Update job to set start step:
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job
       @job_name=@job_name, 
       @enabled=1, 
       @start_step_id=1, 
       @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
       @notify_level_email=2, 
       @notify_level_netsend=2, 
       @notify_level_page=2, 
       @delete_level=0, 
       @description=@description, 
       @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
       @owner_login_name=@owner_login_name, 
       @notify_email_operator_name=N'', 
       @notify_netsend_operator_name=N'', 
       @notify_page_operator_name=N'';

  -- Schedule job:
   EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule
       @job_name=@job_name,
       @name=N'Daily',
       @enabled=1,
       @freq_type=4,
       @freq_interval=1, 
       @freq_subday_type=1, 
       @freq_subday_interval=0, 
       @freq_relative_interval=0, 
       @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
       @active_start_date=20170101, --YYYYMMDD
       @active_end_date=99991231, --YYYYMMDD (this represents no end date)
       @active_start_time=010000, --HHMMSS
       @active_end_time=235959; --HHMMSS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sql-server supports running R and python since sql-server 2014. Take a look on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-using-r-functions-with-sql-server-data?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014).

**Method before sql-server 2014**

However if you are using version before 2014, you need to have some other way else. My suggestion is using R to kick start the sql (if you can).

Using library like [taskscheduleR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taskscheduleR/vignettes/taskscheduleR.html). You first make a schedule task of R for computing your data. And then connect to your sql-server by some library like [obdc, dbi, etc.](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/10/18/database-queries-with-r/) to update what you want.

ps. I didn't try this before, but I can make some test if you still have further problem about it.